# Configuring before process hook for rollbar gem on initializer does not support method before_process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rollbar

My rollbar gem (1.2.13) initializer setup:

```
Rollbar.configure do |config|
  config.before_process << handler
end
```

This config is raising no method error. Any one could report a success case or any tip?

`undefined method 'before_process' for #<Rollbar::Configuration:0x007f34b6a4d6b0> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Please specify your version on Rollbar gem.

Comment: @31piy 1.2.13 , ty. Edited

Comment: If you observe the code for release [version 1.2.13](https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-gem/releases/tag/v1.2.13), there is no method `before_process` in there.

Comment: just checked =x, ty

Answer (score 0):

`Rollbar::Configuration#before_process` was added in version 2.8.0 of the gem, https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-gem/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#280.